# Laravel: Validate array fields to have the same size

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a form that will accept multiple images to upload. The form fields are `img` (the image file itself), `img_alt`, and `img_caption`. I need to make sure that the number of images is equal to the number of captions and the number of `alt` (the img HTML attribute). For example, I do not want to have 7 captions and 3 images.

Is there a built-in way to do this in Laravel?

I'm aware I can create custom validations and I'm doing this right now. However, I'd like to know if this validation is ready in Laravel. Couldn't find it in [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-same)

Maybe there is another solution, not using Laravel, but using HTML. I think I've read something about creating a field array `images[]` and each of its elements would be actually 3 other fields, like `images.alt`, `images.caption`, `images.file`, and it would accessible in PHP through`images[0]['alt']`, `images[1]['alt']`, etc. I'm not sure if this is possible and, if it is, can someone tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the following syntax:

```
<input type="text" name="images[0][caption]" />
<input type="text" name="images[0][alt]" />
<input type="file" name="images[0][filename]" />

<input type="text" name="images[1][caption]" />
<input type="text" name="images[1][alt]" />
<input type="file" name="images[1][filename]" />
```

Which will post an array of objects to the server:

```
[
    {
        "caption": "What a cute dog!",
        "alt": "A young brown puppy playing with a toy.",
        "filename": "1293874123_dog.jpg"
    },
    {
        "caption": "Doggo Selfie",
        "alt": "A dog taking a picture of itself.",
        "filename": "1234123255_dog_selfie.jpg"
    }
]
```

In order to validate the input, you will need the following validation rules:

```
$rules = [
    'images' => 'required|array',
    'images.*.caption' => 'required|string|min:10',
    'images.*.alt' => 'nullable|string|min:3',
    'images.*.filename' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,png,bmp,webp'
];
```

Obviously, these are only examples and may need customization according to your exact needs. The rules implicitely require the array to contain objects. If you need all three fields to always be filled, simply require them.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Actually, this did not work. If I try to submit two images, then `var_dump($request->all())`, the array `img` will have 6 elements and these 6 elements are arrays. Here the what I get from `var_dump`:  `["img"]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(1) { ["alt"]=> string(2) "1a" } [1]=> array(1) { ["caption"]=> string(2) "1a" } [2]=> array(1) { ["file"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(1) { ["alt"]=> string(2) "2a" } [5]=> array(1) { ["caption"]=> string(2) "2a" } [6]=> array(1) { ["file"]=> NULL } }`.

Comment: I appreciate if you can help me again!

Comment: Mh yeah, that makes sense. You might need an index in the first array like 0, 1, 2,...

Comment: I updated the answer regarding the HTML part. You simply need a numeric index in order to group the elements.